# How to change pdfview to single page mode in cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa

I've been writing a PDF viewer in cocoa using swift and I was wondering if there's a way to make PDFs display only one page at a time by default. The only thing I've managed to find is right-clicking on the viewer and changing it there, but there must be a way to do it in the code, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
myPDFView.displayMode = .singlePage
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the `displayMode` property on the `PDFView`.

Comment: Thanks but what do I set it to?

Comment: "See Constants for possible values."

Comment: So you click on the [helpful link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdisplaymode) for `PDFDisplayMode` and you see what the possible values are. Having now RTFM, it should be clear to you what you should do.

Comment: Read the section of the Swift manual about enums and how to use them:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145